# jQuery resizable moving my div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resizable

I'm trying to build a page with 3 resizable divs.
The first one is on the left, called "middle_explorer"
The second one is on the bottom, called "middle_console"
The last one is on the left, called "middle_info"

The problem is that when I try to resize the second and the last, they doesn't still where they should...
Have a look by yourself [here](http://atomcodepad.com/newui/)

Here is my page :

```
<header>
        <div id="header_logo">header_logo</div>
        <div id="header_controls">header_controls</div>
    </header>
    <section id="middle">
        <div id="middle_controls">middle_controls</div>
        <div id="middle_workarea">
            <div id="middle_explorer" class="sidebar">middle_explorer</div>
            <div id="middle_main">
                <div id="middle_codecontainer">middle_codecontainer</div>
                <div id="middle_console">middle_console</div>
            </div>
            <div id="middle_info" class="sidebar">middle_info</div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <div id="footer_date"></div>
    </footer>
```

Some css property are set by js, #middle_main's width, for example.
Here is my css:

```
#middle_info{
    width: 150px;
    max-width: 250px;
    float: left;
}
#middle_codecontainer{
    /* Width is determined by acpUi.js */
}
#middle_console{
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    background: white;
    padding: 2px;
}
#middle_main{
    /* Width is determined by acpUi.js */
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-image: url('res/bkg02.png');
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
#middle_workarea{
    /* Height is determined by acpUi.js */
}
#middle_explorer{
    width: 200px;
    max-width: 400px;
    float: left;
}
```

And here is the code I was just talking about:

```
/* Adjust the #middle height according to the header and the footer */
function middleHeight () {
    $("#middle").height($(document).height() - $("header").height() - $("footer").height());
}
/* Adjust the #middle_workarea height according to the #middle_controls div height (37px) */
function workareaHeight () {
    $("#middle_workarea").height($("#middle").height() - 37);
}
/* Adjust the #code_main width according to the #middle_explorer, #middle_info */
function mainWidth () {
    var width = ($("#middle_workarea").width() - $("#middle_explorer").width() - $("#middle_info").width());
    $("#middle_main").width(width);
}
/* Adjust the #middle_codecontainer height */
function codecontainerHeight (){
    var height = ($("#middle_workarea").height() - $("#middle_console").height());
    $("#middle_codecontainer").height(height);
}
```

Here is the code I used to make my divs resizable:

```
$("#middle_explorer").resizable({ handles: "e"});
$("#middle_info").resizable({ handles: "w"});
$("#middle_console").resizable({ handles: "n", maxHeight: $("#middle_codecontainer").height()});
```

As you can see, the #middle_explorer stay anchored to the left while resized but the two other doesn't and I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: you should really post some code here if you want an answer

Comment: Knowing the CSS is vital here, you might want to include it.